# Return 0 when no results is returned in a Join Query for PostgreSQL 9.2 Database after using Coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I Need help have written a query in PostgreSQL 9.2 as below I need to 
Return rows indicating zero when there’s no results, currently its returning no records even after trying to use COALESCE.

```
With S as (select test.Name as Test,result.value as result,concat(person.first_name,' ', person.last_name) as "Name",
extract (Year from (select  (age (patient.birth_date)))) as age
from  clinlims.analysis
INNER JOIN clinlims.test on analysis.test_id=test.id
INNER JOIN clinlims.result on analysis.id = result.analysis_id
INNER JOIN clinlims.sample_item on sample_item.id = analysis.sampitem_id
INNER JOIN clinlims.sample_human on sample_human.samp_id = sample_item.samp_id
INNER JOIN clinlims.patient on patient.id = sample_human.patient_id
INNER JOIN clinlims.person on person.id = patient.person_id)

select  Test , coalesce (count(*),0) as "Number Positive" 
from S where result = 'value' and test = 'Haemoglobin' 
group by Test
```

I have checked the solution here [PostgreSQL - count data as zero if it is null (when where clause is used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405207/postgresql-count-data-as-zero-if-it-is-null-when-where-clause-is-used)

but it’s not working in my case since  I don’t want to move my where condition  in the S TABLE since I will be querying  from it using different queries later on.
Is it possible ?

Comment: That's because there are no records matching the filter `where result = 'value' and test = 'Haemoglobin'`. What output do you want when there are no records found?

Comment: my out put as indicated in the question ,i want it to return zero

Answer (score 0):

Consider summing the conditional of `WHERE` clause:

```
select  Test, 
        sum((result = 'value' and test = 'Haemoglobin')::integer) as "Number Positive" 
from S
group by Test
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply but the above isnt working

Comment: Why isn't it working? Do you receive any errors or undesired results? See this demo using random data: https://rextester.com/MZR65796. The conditional aggregation as shown here does count *Postgres* and *True* rows with zeroes showing.